# /usr and /etc changed ownership to user "5640" and group "13023". What happened?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, root, ownership

after just installing samba on my Ubuntu server, I got warnings (from the samba installer) about strange ownership and permissions set for my `/etc` and `/usr` folders.
I checked and indeed `/etc` and `/usr` are currently owned by user "5640" and group "13023".
Neither this user nor that group exist on my system (checked `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`).

here is what my root-folder looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root     4096 Jun 26 06:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root     4096 Jun 26 06:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 May 20 08:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root     4096 Jun 27 06:54 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Nov 20  2019 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root     4020 Jun 18 13:43 dev
drwxrwxr-x 159 5640 13023   12288 Jun 30 12:36 etc
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root     4096 May 29 11:34 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       34 Jun 26 06:54 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-108-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       34 Jun 26 06:54 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8114876 Nov 25  2019 jkweb.a
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root     4096 Apr  8 16:58 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug  5  2019 lib64
drwx------   2 root root    16384 Nov 20  2019 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug  5  2019 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug  5  2019 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root     4096 Apr  8 16:58 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 843 root root        0 Nov 20  2019 proc
drwx------   7 root root     4096 Mar 18 19:49 root
drwxr-xr-x  36 root root     1360 Jun 30 12:36 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    12288 Jun 23 06:41 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root     4096 Nov 20  2019 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug  5  2019 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root        0 Dec  4  2019 sys
drwxrwxrwt 338 root root   262144 Jun 30 12:47 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  10 5640 13023    4096 May 21 20:16 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root     4096 Nov 20  2019 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       31 Jun 26 06:54 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-108-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       31 Jun 26 06:54 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-106-generic
```

How can this have happened? Do I need to be worried? Can I just change the ownership back to "root" and revoke the write permission for group, or are those ownerships set like that for an important reason?